# How to resolve dependency of other project's jar in my web project while using maven package command?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

I have one java web project which is having pom.xml as mention below.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.csam.product</groupId>
    <artifactId>wallet-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>wallet-server</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>3.0</version>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>wallet-server</finalName>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.csam.enabling</groupId>
            <artifactId>comms</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.csam.enabling</groupId>
            <artifactId>user_profile</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.csam.enabling</groupId>
            <artifactId>wallet</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.csam.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>payment_card_service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.27</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.13</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.csam.enabling</groupId>
            <artifactId>message_replay_detector</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.3.Final</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

in that comms,user_profile,wallet,payment_card_service are the dependencies of other projects.

Now, when i am trying to fire **mvn compile** or **mvn package** command on my this project, it'll giving me an error as mention below,

```
[ERROR] /E:/cvs-projects-command/customers/prd_mno_nfc_wallet/server/webtier/src/main/java/com/csam/product/se_wallet/view/wallet/ChangeServicesController.java:[14,59] E:\cvs-projects-command\customers\prd_mno_nfc_wallet\server\webtier\src\main\java\com\csam\product\se_wallet\view\wallet\ChangeServicesController.java:14: package com.csam.product.se_wallet.comms.emvelopeprocessing does not exist
[ERROR] /E:/cvs-projects-command/customers/prd_mno_nfc_wallet/server/webtier/src/main/java/com/csam/product/se_wallet/view/wallet/ChangeServicesController.java:[15,59] E:\cvs-projects-command\customers\prd_mno_nfc_wallet\server\webtier\src\main\java\com\csam\product\se_wallet\view\wallet\ChangeServicesController.java:15: package com.csam.product.se_wallet.comms.emvelopeprocessing does not exist
[ERROR] /E:/cvs-projects-command/customers/prd_mno_nfc_wallet/server/webtier/src/main/java/com/csam/product/se_wallet/view/wallet/ChangeServicesController.java:[16,50] E:\cvs-projects-command\customers\prd_mno_nfc_wallet\server\webtier\src\main\java\com\csam\product\se_wallet\view\wallet\ChangeServicesController.java:16: package com.csam.product.se_wallet.comms.validator does not exist
[ERROR] /E:/cvs-projects-command/customers/prd_mno_nfc_wallet/server/webtier/src/main/java/com/csam/product/se_wallet/view/wallet/ChangeServicesController.java:[24,45] E:\cvs-projects-command\customers\prd_mno_nfc_wallet\server\webtier\src\main\java\com\csam\product\se_wallet\view\wallet\ChangeServicesController.java:24: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ChangeService
location: package com.csam.wsc.service.wallet.lifecycle
[ERROR] /E:/cvs-projects-command/customers/prd_mno_nfc_wallet/server/webtier/src/main/java/com/csam/product/se_wallet/view/wallet/ChangeServicesController.java:[75,81] E:\cvs-projects-command\customers\prd_mno_nfc_wallet\server\webtier\src\main\java\com\csam\product\se_wallet\view\wallet\ChangeServicesController.java:75: package com.csam.product.se_wallet.comms.emvelopeprocessing does not exist
[ERROR] /E:/cvs-projects-command/customers/prd_mno_nfc_wallet/server/webtier/src/main/java/com/csam/product/se_wallet/view/wallet/ChangeServicesController.java:[81,17] E:\cvs-projects-command\customers\prd_mno_nfc_wallet\server\webtier\src\main\java\com\csam\product\se_wallet\view\wallet\ChangeServicesController.java:81: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ChangeService
location: class com.csam.product.se_wallet.view.wallet.ChangeServicesController
[ERROR] /E:/cvs-projects-command/customers/prd_mno_nfc_wallet/server/webtier/src/main/java/com/csam/product/se_wallet/view/wallet/ChangeServicesController.java:[300,89] E:\cvs-projects-command\customers\prd_mno_nfc_wallet\server\webtier\src\main\java\com\csam\product\se_wallet\view\wallet\ChangeServicesController.java:300: package com.csam.product.se_wallet.comms.emvelopeprocessing does not exist
[ERROR] /E:/cvs-projects-command/customers/prd_mno_nfc_wallet/server/webtier/src/main/java/com/csam/product/se_wallet/view/wallet/ChangeServicesController.java:[320,31] E:\cvs-projects-command\customers\prd_mno_nfc_wallet\server\webtier\src\main\java\com\csam\product\se_wallet\view\wallet\ChangeServicesController.java:320: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ChangeService
location: class com.csam.product.se_wallet.view.wallet.ChangeServicesController
```

that means it's not getting the dependent jars of other projects.

So is there any way to resolve this problem ?
Please help....

Comment: Do you have those dependencies in you local repository?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to find the CVS Path, but cannot find the class ChangeService and the packages com.csam.product.se_wallet.comms.emvelopeprocessing, com.csam.product.se_wallet.comms.validator

Are you sure that this class and the other packages are committed...

try to commit those struff again..

Answer (score 0):

You have two projets: Blammo and wallet-server.

#### Option 1

1. Use maven when building Blammo and execute the `install` maven task when building Blammo.
   This will update the Blammo snapshot in your local maven repository.
2. Add a dependancy to the Blammo snapshot in your wallet-server pom file.
   Do not update snapshots during this build unless you also add the Blammo snapshot to your local nexus.

#### Option 2

Use option 1, but if you hate doing things that way, do the following:

1. Build Blammo into a jar however you want.
2. Manually add the Blammo jar to your local maven repository.
3. Add a dependancy to the Blammo snapshot in your wallet-server pom file.
   Do not update snapshots during this build unless you also add the Blammo snapshot to your local nexus.

Answer (score 0):

Those dependencies does not seem to be present in your local repository. 
If you compiled those dependencies locally you may want check if you did run "mvn install".
Otherwise, Check if your settings.xml or your pom/parent pom refers the repository that contains those dependencies.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html